# Is Microsoft SQL Managed Instance maximum backup file size still limited to 195 GB?

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

Is this 195 GB maximum strip size still accurate? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current#limitations-for-sql-managed-instance.

[image: SQL Managed Instance maximum backup size]

Microsoft has increased the maximum size for a single Blob in Azure Blob storage to 4 TB, so is SQL MI backup is still limited to 195 GB?

Since Azure Blob storage allows up to 4 TB, I assume SQL MI should also be limited to 4 TB?